# how should i import css and js files from my template to webpack in angular 5 project

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a html template with a bunch of css and js files that want to import to angular 5 project using webpack. I am lost in all the training in the internet and didn't find anything like my problem.

i've read somewhere to import css to my style.css like this

```
   @import './assets/css/icons.css';
```

and works fine for me. But i didn't find anything for my js files.
i appreciate someone to point me to right path. this is my webpack.config.json

```
  const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] },
                { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize', 'sass-loader'] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module#AppModule')
                })
            ])
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig];
};
```

Comment: are you using angular-cli in your project?

Comment: You could just import them in your main.ts with import LIBRARY from ./path/to/lib.js, include the script in your angular-cli.json in the scripts array, or import them in your index.html in a script tag

Comment: Yes i'm using angular-cli in my project.

Comment: @darron614 i inserted all js files in script array of angular-cli.json like this          "assets/js/waves.js",
        "assets/js/wow.min.js",
        "assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js",
        "assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js",
        "assets/js/jquery.core.js",
        "assets/js/jquery.app.js"
but no luck. should i do something more? i want to know the right way to do this actually. i can insert them in head of  my html but i think that not the right way

Comment: Are your sure the paths are correct? Also you have to rerun "ng serve", so webpack bundles your newly included js files.

Comment: assets folder is in ClientApp/app/assets path. I think thats is right path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add them in entry object like this:

```
 entry: {
  // other things,
  scripts: [
    "script-loader!./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "script-loader!./src/plugins/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "script-loader!./node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js",

  ],
  styles: [
    "./src/styles.scss"
  ]
},
```

Do not forget to add `script-loader!` before js paths.